# WooCommerce Rest API gives syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, curl, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm working on a side project and I've been trying to interact with the WooCommerce REST API.

I have everything seemingly correct. I've created the proper keys because they work with cURL. But when I try to utilize the php-wrapper, provided by Automattic, everything stops working.

I have the code set up exactly like they've instructed:
    require **DIR** . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://mywebsitenamegoeshere.com',
    '##########',
    '##########',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
        'query_string_auth' => true
    ]
);
```

I'm simply trying to do a request to list the endpoints (which also works with cURL) but as soon as I attempt to interact via the php-wrapper I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException' with message 'Syntax error' in /nas/content/live/wwitssltest/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:346 
Stack trace: #0 /nas/content/live/wwitssltest/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(385): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->processResponse() 
#1 /nas/content/live/wwitssltest/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/Client.php(82): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('', 'GET', Array, Array) 
#2 /nas/content/live/wwitssltest/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/ticket-data-test-template.php(15): Automattic\WooCommerce\Client->get('') 
#3 /nas/content/live/wwitssltest/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74): include('/nas/content/li...') 
#4 /nas/content/live/wwitssltest/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/nas/content/li...') 
#5 /nas/content in /nas/content/live/wwitssltest/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php on line 346
```

When I look in the files, specifically `HttpClient.php` the most specific information I can come across is that the JSON might not be formatted properly?

The [documentation](https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce) seems pretty cut and dry but nothing I do makes any difference.

With the exception of `<php print_r( $woocommerce ); ?>` which returns the Client object.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: I did not solve the problem. I then moved on to a different project.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after `query_string_auth' => true`.
It should be: `query_string_auth' => true`.

Cheers!